Can marriage take place after 3 months death of a young boy (Age 25) in family
On 11 march 2024 ,   Our marriage dates were fixed for 2 december 2024 , we had one small ceremony on april 11 2024 but now on 3rd september the girl's side , her real cousin met with an accident and sadly he died he was only 25 years old , so now according to hindu bhramin culture , how long will we have to delay this marriage ? Please provide detailed answers if possible.
